# Zend1: redirect to action in different module

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

My `loginAction` is in a module `user`, in the controller `application/modules/user/controllers/AuthController.php`. I want to redirect upon successful login to the `indexAction` in `application/controllers/IndexController.php`. So I have this:

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
            $auth->getStorage()->write($adapter->getResultRowObject());

            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');

            return;
}
```

When I now login, I get the message `Message: Invalid controller specified (index)`. I guess it is because my login is in the module `user`, while the `IndexController` is in the root application.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `application/controllers/Index.php` is that a valid controller. It should be like `application/modules/{modulename}/controllers/IndexController.php`

Comment: @NandakumarV That was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: what about module? Are you using both modular and non-modular approach in same application?

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't? I am entirely new to Zend and it seems like I am making mistakes on every single line of code.

Comment: modules in Zf1 are totally optional and you can mix and match with out any issues.

Comment: I am not sure if you should or shouldn't.Actually don't know id it is possible in zend. But it is preferable you don't. There are many sections in zend where if the module is not specified default module (default) will be taken.

Comment: @RockyFord so you are saying that we can use both modular and non-modular approach in the same application? How is the routing possible them?

Comment: @NandakumarV in ZF1 modules don't really exist. The default filesystem built when using Zend_Tool is for most purposes the 'default' module and will route as such when required. Adding additional 'modules' just works (for the most part). Contrast this with ZF2 where modules are enforced, with application being a module itself. I hope this made some sense.

Comment: that was a bit confusing. I have two controllers `application/modules/{modulename}/controllers/IndexController.php` and `application/controllers/IndexController.php`. To which controller will this redirect to `$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index', 'default')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirector() action helper has several methods to redirect the request.

try this, the controllers at *application/controllers* are in the ***'default'*** module:

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
    $auth->getStorage()->write($adapter->getResultRowObject());
    //redirector($action, $controller, $module)
    $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index', 'default');
}
```

The way I prefer to use this helper is more explicit, so I don't have to remember the defaults:

```
 if ($result->isValid()) {
        $auth->getStorage()->write($adapter->getResultRowObject());
        //gotoSimple($action, $controller, $module, $params = array())
        $this->getHelper(redirector)->gotoSimple('index', 'index', 'default');
        //or use gotoUrl($url)
        $this->getHelper(redirector)->gotoUrl('/index/index');
        //or use gotoRoute()
        $this->getHelper(redirector)->gotoRoute('action'=>'index', 'controller'=>'index', 'module' => 'default');
    }
```

and the quick and dirty utility method:

```
 if ($result->isValid()) {
        $auth->getStorage()->write($adapter->getResultRowObject());
        //_redirect($url);
        $this->_redirect('/index/index');
    }
```

Hope this helps