# ZF3 redirect to another controller acton in another module

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zf3

I´m using ZF3 with the Applcation and User modules. The Application module is the default loaded module that contains my index page as a welcome page with no login information. The User module has the login page and all the user authentication stuff.

I need to put a button in my application modula index action page to redirect to the login page at user module index page.

I´m trying to use the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776716/2697571) but it does not seen to work.

```
<p>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="
    <?= $this->getHelper(redirector)->gotoSimple('index', 'index', 'user'); ?>">
    Other module index action
</a>
</p>
```

This is leading to the following error:

**Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException**

**File:**

```
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php 133
```

**Message:**

```
A plugin by the name "getHelper" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager
```

How should I redirect to an action of another module using ZF3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you linked is zendframework 1. There have been a lot of changes made to ZF3 since then.

Also a redirect is something you do inside the controller. e.g. if something is saved successfully to the database you can redirect, within the same request, to another page with a message or view the saved changes.

What you are looking for is the [url helper](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-view/helpers/url/). You use it inside a zend-view template to generate an url.

```
<a href="<?= $this->url('news', ['action' => 'details', 'id' =>42]); ?>">
    Details of News #42
</a>
```

Comment: Clear to me. Thanks.